# dataframe sorting by sum of values

Tags: pandas, sorting

I have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'from':['A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C'],'to':['J','C','F','C','M','Q','C','J'],'amount':[1,1,2,12,13,5,5,1]})
df
```

[image]

and I wish to sort it is such way that the highest amount of 'from' is first. So in this example, 'from' B has 12+13 = 25 so B is the first in the list. Then comes C with 11 and then A with 4.

One way to do it is like this:

```
df['temp'] = df.groupby(['from'])['amount'].transform('sum')
df.sort_values(by=['temp'], ascending =False)
```

[image]

but I'm just adding another column. Wonder if there's a better way?

Comment: This way is good. Add your column as you did, then sort by this column, and finally drop the columns if you don't want it to appear

Answer (score 0):

I think your method is good and explicit.

A variant without the temporary column could be:

```
df.sort_values(by='from', ascending=False,
               key=lambda x: df['amount'].groupby(x).transform('sum'))
```

output:

```
  from to  amount
3    B  C      12
4    B  M      13
5    C  Q       5
6    C  C       5
7    C  J       1
0    A  J       1
1    A  C       1
2    A  F       2
```

Comment: mmm, I get 'sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key' do you think its a pandas version?

Comment: Yes, likely, this is new in pandas 1.1

Comment: But, honestly, your method is good, it enables you to use other columns if needed

Answer (score 0):

In your case do with `argsort`

```
out = df.iloc[(-df.groupby(['from'])['amount'].transform('sum')).argsort()]
Out[53]: 
  from to  amount
3    B  C      12
4    B  M      13
5    C  Q       5
6    C  C       5
7    C  J       1
0    A  J       1
1    A  C       1
2    A  F       2
```